# Sorting object entries with reverse

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have been trying many different approaches to reversing the order of week numbers I have stored in state. I use the weeknum. as an object key with an array of values like

```
{ weeknum: [12, 99, 4] }
```

The current method I'm trying is simply invoking reverseSorting() on an onClick event:

```
reverseSorting() {
  console.log("state before: ", this.state.workloadArr);
  this.setState({workloadArr: Object.entries(this.state.workloadArr).reverse()})
  console.log("state after: ", this.state.workloadArr);
}
```

As you can see from the inspecter it yields som very strange behavior for each click, and sets it's own ids each time the method is invoked.

[image]

I have tried so many different solutions eg. mapping over the array, array.forEach... but it adds it's own keys everytime!

It's sooo frustrating.. hope someone can help?

Comment: [Do not post images of code or errors!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: Can't you just use `myArray.reverse()` - if not then I'm not understanding your problem

Comment: look at the image, it adds 0,1,2,3,4 as keys instead of using the original 25,38,39,40,52 (corresponding to the weeks numbers). It also keeps nesting the array deeper and deeper for each time the method is invoked

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure how the whole data looks like and what you're exactly trying to achieve. But I'm sure that `Object.entries` does not return an array you're looking for. In order to accomplish it correctly, you need to map the values inside entries:

```
Object.entries(this.state.workloadArr).map(([key, value]) => value).reverse();
```

This would return `[4, 99, 12]` in your case.

Comment: As you can see from the inspector (image), the "state before" is how it should look after it has been reversed :)  like:   { weeknum: [ 27, 89 13] }. Why is it that it adds its own indexes from 0,1,2,3,4? Your example does this too

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the keys first and save them in the correct sorted order. Then, loop through your sorted keys and return the matching object.

```
const sortedKeys = Object.keys(this.state.workloadArr).sort( (a, b) => this.state.workloadArr[a] - this.state.workloadArr[b] ).reverse();
const workloadSorted = sortedKeys.map( key => this.state.workloadArr[key] );
this.setState({ workloadArr: workloadSorted });
```